# Flutter Printing package not working for printing PDF on deployed Flutter web app

Tags: flutter, pdf, deployment, printing

I am facing an issue with the Flutter Printing package when trying to print a PDF on a deployed Flutter web app. The following code snippet works perfectly fine in debug mode:

```
await Printing.layoutPdf(
  format: PdfPageFormat.a4,
  onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async {
    return pdf.save();
  },
);
```

It works fine on debig mode with, however, when I deploy the app and access it through the same web browser, the printing functionality does not work.

I expected this code to generate a PDF and open the print dialog on Flutter web, allowing the user to print the PDF. However, nothing happens when I run this code on the deployed app.

The issue persists only when the app is deployed. I am using Flutter version **3.16.1** and the Flutter Printing package version **5.11.1**.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue specifically when deploying the Flutter web app and using the Flutter Printing package for PDF printing.

I have already tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- Ensuring that I have the latest version of the Flutter Printing package.
- Verifying that the Flutter web target is correctly configured in my project.
- Checking that the PDF generation code is working correctly by saving the PDF to a file instead of using the Flutter Printing package.